# Conversión implicita de modelos MVC 4

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, stored-procedure

Tengo el siguiente problema, en un Controller necesito obtener datos dependiendo del perfil de usuario actual.

El modelo es:

```
public IEnumerable<sp_Obtener_Todos_Ejecutivos_Result> TodosEjecutivos { get; set; }
```

Y para obtener los datos llamo al *Stored Procedure*:

```
public List<sp_Obtener_Todos_Ejecutivos_Result> ObtenerTodosEjecutivos() {
    try {
        WorkflowIniciativasEntities entities = new WorkflowIniciativasEntities();
        return entities.sp_Obtener_Todos_Ejecutivos().ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.Error("Error al obtener lista de ejecutivos.", e);
        return new List<sp_Obtener_Todos_Ejecutivos_Result>();
    }
}
```

Los datos los toma el Model en el Controller:

```
model.TodosEjecutivos = bl_Ejecutivos.GetInstance().ObtenerEjecutivosJefe(userApp);
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, eso funciona bajo el perfil de ejecutivos, pero si quiero obtener los datos con un usuario de perfil "Jefe de ventas", necesito llamar a otro *Stored Procedure*:

```
public List<sp_Obtener_Ejecutivos_Por_Jefe_Result> ObtieneEjecutivosPorJefe(string userJefe) {
    try {
        WorkflowIniciativasEntities dbSpcServicios = new WorkflowIniciativasEntities();
        return dbSpcServicios.sp_Obtener_Ejecutivos_Por_Jefe(userJefe).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.Error("Error al obtener lista de ejecutivos.", e);
        return new List<sp_Obtener_Ejecutivos_Por_Jefe_Result>();
    }
}
```

Y al llamar al método que me retorna la lista de ejecutivos por jefe, me aparece el error de una conversion implícita, el *Stored Procedure* es distinto, pero el tipo de datos devuelto es exactamente el mismo en ambos casos, el tipo de dato del modelo hace referencia al primer *Stored Procedure*.

Mi pregunta es, ¿existe alguna forma de hacer esa conversión en el segundo caso, para adaptar los datos devueltos al modelo?

Comment: ¿Los datos que te envían ambos SP son exactamente los mismos? ¿Podrías poner el contenido de los dos SPs? Igual y el tema va más va por el lado de que en lugar tengas dos SPs lo simplifiques a uno solo.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendaria hagas uso de herencia, entonces si tienes diferentes clases pero ambas tienen la misma estructura podria ser

```
public class EjecutivosResultBase
{
   //aqui defines las propiedades comunes
}

public class sp_Obtener_Ejecutivos_Por_Jefe_Result : EjecutivosResultBase
{
}

public class sp_Obtener_Todos_Ejecutivos_Result : EjecutivosResultBase
{
}
```

entonces tu action puede normalizar la propiedad del modelo usando

```
public IEnumerable<EjecutivosResultBase> TodosEjecutivos { get; set; }
```

de esta forma no importa que procedure se invoque ya que todos devolveran datos en base a una clase comun

La entidad que declare entity framework deberia poder extenderse para agregar esta herencia.

Comment: Leandro, tienes algun canal donde se te pueda hacer una consulta?

Comment: @sioesi canal no tengo, pero si accedes a mi blog podras encontrar mi mail

Comment: Perfecto, te contactare a tu email, saludos!

Comment: no encuentro tu correo, me puedes escribir a nicolas.hernandez222@gmail.com o dejarme tu correo? Saludos!